# Como trabalhar com Editor do PrimeNG?

Tags: angular

Observem o link

[Edidor PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor)

Alguém saberia como faço para desabilitar ou tirar o botão de upload de imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Wladyband se vc tiver alguma dúvida sobre como fazer o Override de CSS me fala que eu edito a resposta com mais detalhes. Mas basta colocar essa folha de estilo por último, depois que já tiver chamado todas as outras.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vc pode criar um .css para fazer um `override` das classes que deseja mudar.

No caso para tirar esse botão vc pode fazer assim:

```
button.ql-image {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Veja uma imagem com o resultado (repare no box vermelho).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor)

> Editor provides a default toolbar with common options, to
>   customize it define your elements inside the `header` element.

Traduzindo

> Editor fornece uma barra de ferramentas padrão com opções comuns, para customizá-la defina seus elementos dentro do elemento `header`

Por exemplo

```html
<p-editor name="custom" [(ngModel)]="customtext" styleClass="editor-dimensions">
  <p-header>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-clean"></button>
    </span>
  </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

Vai renderizar como

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira um nível mais alto de customização, dê uma lida na documentação do [Quill toolbar](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/), que é o que o PrimeNG usa.

Comment: Eu até conhecia essa sugestão que você mecionou, mas o que estou precisando mesmo e colocar todos os botões menos o de upload, você saberia modificar o p-header para colocar todos menos o botão de upload? por favor.

Comment: eu não encontrei na documentação como fazer isso.